# window.onload not working to submit a for automatically

Tags: javascript, forms

Can you tell why my form is not submitted automatically ?

```
<form action="../../../socialnetwork/index.php" method="post" name="hid" id="hid">
    <input type="hidden" name="UM_email" value="<?php echo $user_data->email; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="provider" value="<?php echo $provider_adapter->user()->providerId; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunc () {
//alert("loading....") its working
    var frm = document.getElementById("hid");
    frm.submit();
}
window.onload = myfunc;
</script>
```

Comment: Firefox 5.0 . No error but in the same page with submit button . If I click there then only values are submitted,but I want it to submit automatically as soon as page loads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is caused by the `<input type="submit" name="submit"` button.. change name to something like this name="button_submit" and it will work

Comment: it was overriding the submit function ;) i have made that mistake a thousand times ;) input types with name submit.. cuz it is an submit button.. but that will override the javascript submit function :(

Answer (score 0):

Is something else overriding the `window.onload` property?  A better way to achieve the same would be this:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', myfunc, false);
} else {
  window.attachEvent('onload', myfunc);
}
```

If you don't need to support IE less than version 9, you can skip the whole if/else and just use `addEventListener` directly.

Also, you may want to just use a javascript library to set the handler, that way browser differences are abstracted out (you don't have to worry about them).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `name="button_submit"` instead of `name="submit"` in input type.